# Button in Form 4 doesn't fire in Form 1

Tags: c#, forms, button, constructor

The objective is to click Button1 in FORM4 which then allows for WebBrowser1 in FORM1 to navigate to that site.

I Keep getting this error:
Error   1   'NO1.Form4' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Form 1

```
    Form4 mForm;
    private void button92_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          if (mForm == null) 
          {
          mForm = new Form4();
          mForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(mForm_FormClosed);
          mForm.Show();
             }
        else 
          {
         if (mForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
           mForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
          mForm.Focus();
          }
}

void mForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
  mForm = null;
}
```

Form 4

```
        public partial class Form4 : Form

        {

   private Form1 m_parent;
    public Form4(Form1 frm1)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        m_parent = frm1;

    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_parent.webBrowser1.Navigate("google.com");
    }

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but a good idea, you should consider adopting a naming convention for your code. Names like `button92`, `Form1` and `Form4` are totally unhelpful for efficient coding or debugging. Use names that help indicate what the view/component is, ex: `WebBrowserView` and `BrowserLauncherView` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your function to be like this (add `this` to the constructor):

```
private void button92_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (mForm == null) 
     {
         mForm = new Form4(this);
         mForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(mForm_FormClosed);
         mForm.Show();
     }
     else 
     {
         if (mForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
             mForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
          mForm.Focus();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Form4` class has only one constructor and that has an argument of `Form1`.

By the looks of it you want to pass your `Form1` instance into the `Form4` constructor in the click event

```
if (mForm == null)
{
    mForm = new Form4(this);
    mForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(mForm_FormClosed);
    mForm.Show();
}
```